# Using external identity provider in akka http

Tags: scala, oauth-2.0, akka, openid-connect, akka-http

I'm implementing a service in scala using akka-http for building some routes. There is a requirement to use company's internal identity provider to authenticate and authorize users that's using openid-connect and oAuth2.

While I could find some client libraries that could allow me to connect to IDP in Java, I'm unable to find any existing solution that works for akka-http.

Any thoughts that doesn't require me to implement this low level detail on my own? I'm trying not to move away from akka-http.

I appreciate any help or direction

Comment: I would reuse the Java library from Akka HTTP. Indeed there doesn't seem to be an OOB implementation. There's some helpers though: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/security-directives/index.html#low-level-oauth2-directives

Comment: If I understand that correctly, you're suggesting that I use akka-http in Java fashion and use some of the other Java libraries that have implemented redirection and validation logic of using an identity provider? Perhaps one of these https://oauth.net/code/java/

Comment: I'm not familiar with Akka HTTP but you can probably implement some kind of filter or directive in which you use the Java library of your choice to do the OIDC integration.

Comment: What I've found so far is that the libraries typically serve the end-client or help implement the server. I'm yet to find a good library that supports services who wants to just use the external identity provider

Comment: Can you please modify your question to explain why do you want to connect to the IDP and what is the flow you expect to have? If you already have an OAuth 2 authorization server in place and you are implementing the resource server I don't see what you need to implement at a low level.